# Finding a orthogonal matrix that fits $f(S(x,y,z)^t) = ax²+bx²+cx²$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

> Consider the function $$ f(x, y, z) := x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - \sqrt{2} x y + \sqrt{2} y z $$ Find an orthogonal $3 \times 3$ matrix $S$ and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \Bbb R$ with $$f(S(x, y, z)^t) = \alpha x^2 + \beta y^2 + \gamma z^2$$ Note: First write $f$ in the form $f(x) = (Ax) - x$ with asymmetrical $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$.

---

I tried and came to following representation for the function as matrix:

\begin{equation}
A=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & -\frac{1} {\sqrt2} & 0\\
   -\frac{1} {\sqrt2} & 1  & \frac{1} {\sqrt2}\\   
   0 & \frac{1} {\sqrt2} & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{matrix}
(A⋅x)^t⋅x = x^2+y^2-\sqrt{2}⋅x⋅y+z^2+\sqrt{2}⋅y⋅z
\end{matrix}

This looked good to me. Now, I wanted to calculate the eigenvectors for this :

$$
u_{1} = \left(\begin{matrix}
-1 \\
-\sqrt{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right), u_2=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{matrix}\right), u_3=\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 \\
\sqrt{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
However, when I use these vectors as my matrix S, it is not symetric and $$S^TS \neq E$$ So, what should I do instead. According to ChatGPT the values α, β, γ are the eigenvalues (0, 1, 2). But as it is right now, I don't think this is correct. I am not really going anywhere since then, so I wanted to ask what to do now/instead.
$$ \ $$
Thank you!

Comment: You need to normalize your eigenvectors.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is esentially correct: $S$ is the change of basis matrix from the basis $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ to the standard basis. However, note that $S$ is orthogonal iff the basis $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is orthonormal. Hence, since your $u_i$’s are already orthogonal, the last thing that you need to do is normalize the basis of eigenvectors $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$, i.e., taking $u_i/\lVert u_i\rVert$ instead of $u_i$.

Comment: Hey, so I did normalize it. How can I check whether it's right or not. If I add it to (Ax)^t x for A, I don't get the eigenvalues as coefficients. Is it still correct? My values are like -1/2 and 0 and 1/2

Comment: Well, after normalization you will see that $S^T = S^{-1}$, so $S^T A S = S^{-1} A S$, which will be equal to a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, the eigenvalues of $A$.